# Set Google Script to retrieve the value of a certain cell and record that every day/week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am using a Google Sheet to track my portfolio and I have a cell that calculates the total current market value of my portfolio from various parts of the sheet.

I am trying to see if it is possible to create a script that will record the date as well as the market value (the value only, not the formula) automatically from this cell every day. I know it is possible to set a trigger to run the code weekly/daily, but am having trouble with the code itself.

I can think of 2 approaches. I wasn't sure how to code the second implementation, and what I have so far for the first implementation is below.

1) (First, use Cell A1 as a counter. Set initial value to, say, 3.)

```
function recordValue() {
  //read the counter in Cell A1
  var counter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("A1")

  //record current date in cell B&(contents of cell A1)
  var dateCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("B"&counter)
  outputRange.setValues(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'MM-dd-yyyy'));


  //read the current market value in 'Summary'!A1 and record it in cell C&(contents of cell A1)
  var marketValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A1:A1");
  var outputCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("C"&counter);
  outputCell.setValues(marketValue);

  //add 1 to the counter in cell A1
  counter.setValues(counter + 1);
};
```

2) Record the current date in the cell directly below, then read the current market value in 'SheetA'!A1 and record it in the cell to the right of the date. Then create a new, empty row directly below (ie pushing the recently written data down by one row)

I'm new to Google Sheets and don't have much programming knowledge. Will either of the above approaches work (and work well with a time-driven trigger)? What's wrong with the current code I have for the first implemetation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code because you don't use the getValue() .

I don't really understand exactly what you want to do but the code below works :

```
function recordValue() {
  //read the counter in Cell A1
  var counter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("A1");

  //record current date in cell B&(contents of cell A1)
  var dateCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("B"+counter.getValue());
  dateCell.setValue(new Date());


  //read the current market value in 'Summary'!A1 and record it in cell C&(contents of cell A1)
  var marketValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A1");
  var outputCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ThisSheet").getRange("C"+counter.getValue());
  outputCell.setValue(marketValue.getValue());

  //add 1 to the counter in cell A1
  counter.setValue(counter.getValue() + 1);
}
```